# PyQt and MatPlotLib - Embedded Bar Chart Starts at Origin

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt4, bar-chart

I am trying to reproduce [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) chart embedded in a PyQt GUI but there is a problem with what my code

```
N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = self.axes.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='#d62728', yerr=menStd)
p2 = self.axes.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
         bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

self.axes.set_ylabel('Scores')
self.axes.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
self.axes.set_xticks(ind)
self.axes.set_xticklabels(['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'])
self.axes.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
self.axes.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))
```

produces.

[image]

G1 should not be exactly at the origin but a little along. What needs to be changed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you link to is for matplotlib version 2.0. However you are running 1.5 or below. So you need to refer to the example of the previous versions: [bar_stacked example](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) for 1.5.
Alternatively, you can update matplotlib to version 2.0.

The alternative would be to use the [`align` argument to `bar`](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar)

```
plt.bar(... , align="center")
```